# TeamCity - NuGet Pack Build Step - No Content

Tags: nuget, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Is there a way to instruct nuget not to include a content folder in the package when building the package via the TeamCity NuGet PacK build step?

I'm using the csproj to build the package, not a nuspec file.  I'm hoping I can avoid having to write and maintain nuspec files.  All of the packages in question are component libs with no content, although the repos contain files that by default the NuGet Pack step adds as content.  I could use the exclude switch although this will need to be maintained for each package.  A global NoContent switch would be ideal in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your C# project, make sure that there are no items marked with a `Build Action` of `Content`. That is what NuGet is using to determine which files are added as content.